# How can I change height of UIView that already has height anchor?

Tags: ios, swift, nslayoutconstraint

If I have this for a child view controller:

```
autoCompleteViewController.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            autoCompleteViewController.view.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor, constant: 0),
            autoCompleteViewController.view.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor, constant: 0),
            autoCompleteViewController.view.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor, constant: 0),
            autoCompleteViewController.view.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: googleMapViewController.view.topAnchor, constant: 0),
            autoCompleteViewController.view.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 44.0)
        ])
```

how can I change its height and update `heightAnchor`? I've tried this:

```
autoCompleteViewController
            .view
            .heightAnchor
            .constraint(equalToConstant: initialHeightAutoCompleteViewController + CGFloat(numberOfSuggestions * 45))
            .isActive = true
```

but with no luck. I also tried to add `layoutIfNeeded()` and some other similar methods but it didn't work. How can I update view height with anchors?

Comment: I did never did this programmatically, but can you not make a reference to the height anchor as a variable? That way you can do heightVariable.constant += randomIntValue, and after that call UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.0{  self.view.layoutIfNeeded})

Comment: Wrng attempt. Whenever you update constraints by code then first you have to remove the previous constraints on the components and then you have to give the constraints again.

Comment: @dahiya_boy - wrong answer! :-) Sure, you *can* remove the previous constraint, but that's only *one* of at least three options. The other two - and there may be more - are (1) **deactivate** said constraint before adding one that replaces it and (2) **update** said constraint.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Additionally to @Mukesh answer is simply **updating** the constraint:

```
var heightAnchor:NSLayoutConstraint!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    heightAnchor = autoCompleteViewController.view.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant:44.0)
    heightAnchor.isActive = true
}

func changeMyHeight(numberOfSuggestions: Int) {
    heightAnchor.constant = 44.0 + CGFloat(numberOfSuggestions * 45)
}
```

Notes:

- You cannot fully declare this variable at the class level, as `autoCompleteViewController.view` is not yet instantiated.
- You cannot set up the constraint *and* set `isActive = true` at the same time. I've always gotten a build error.

Comment: I've implemented it similar to your solution.

Comment: Very good answer, however one quick addition, I think you don’t need to activate or deactivate the constrain again. Keep the reference to the constraint and just edit the constant value. The view will get modified.

Comment: @Yoku, It's been my experience that you have one of two options - activate/deactivate or add/remove. Even Apple's documentations sets `isActive = true`. Perhaps you are thinking about constraints that are created through Interface Builder? (Those are activated by default. The OP implied that (a) the constraint was created in code and (b) already had a "height anchor", suggesting that using VFL - which likely involves add/remove - isn't a good route to go. https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/ProgrammaticallyCreatingConstraints.html

Comment: @dfd, I commented for programatic setup only. I just wanted to highlight that `isActivate = true` needed only to be done at the setup time, because it relates to the title of the question asked. Later just to change the height, call the function as you created above correctly.

Answer (score 11):

If you don't want to keep a reference to the height anchor, here is an alternative:

```
myVC.view.constraints.forEach { (constraint) in
     if constraint.firstAttribute == .height
     {
         constraint.constant = newHeight
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 5):

First you have disable the previous constraint and activate another

For example

```
let heightAnchor_one = autoCompleteViewController.view.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: x)
let heightAnchor_two = autoCompleteViewController.view.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: y)
heightAnchor_one.isActive = true
heightAnchor_two.isActive = false
```

then whichever constraint you need activate that and disable the other.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var constantValue: CGFloat = 44

    let childView: UIView = {
        let view = UIView()
        view.backgroundColor = .red
        return view
    }()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        view.addSubview(childView)

        childView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            childView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor, constant: 0),
            childView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor, constant: 0),
            childView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor, constant: 0),
            childView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: constantValue)
            ])

    }

    @IBAction func changeHeight(_ sender: UIButton) {

        constantValue = 100

        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, animations: {

            if let constraint = (self.childView.constraints.filter{$0.firstAttribute == .height}.first) {

                constraint.constant = self.constantValue
            }

            self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
        })
    }

}
```

Answer (score -1):

I've fixed it by implementing it like this:

```
autoCompleteViewControllerHeight = NSLayoutConstraint(
            item: autoCompleteViewController.view,
            attribute: .height,
            relatedBy: .equal,
            toItem: nil,
            attribute: .height,
            multiplier: 1.0,
            constant: 44.0)
 guard let autoCompleteViewControllerHeight = autoCompleteViewControllerHeight else { return }
autoCompleteViewControllerHeight.isActive = true
```

and then where it should be changed I added:

```
let newHeight = calculateNewHeight()
 heightConstraintAutoCompleteViewController.constant = newHeight
```

It works like a charm.