# Xcode: Get particular constraint programmatically

Tags: swift, xcode, constraints

I programmatically built in a childVC (DrawerViewController) into my mainVC (HomeController) and now I need the topAnchor reference.

I know I can reference single constraints with IBOutlets and name them but I want to learn how to build stuff programmatically without storyboard. And now I struggle how to correctly reference the topAnchor of my child container programmatically to further work with this var.

As an IBO it would perfectly work like that:

```
@IBOutlet private var containerViewTopConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!
```

So I'd need to reference my topAnchor programmatically and name it into containerViewTopConstraint. The code of the programmatically embeded childVC:

```
let drawerViewController = DrawerViewController()

func addDrawer() {
    addChild(drawerViewController)
    view.addSubview(drawerViewController.view)
    drawerViewController.didMove(toParent: self)
    addDrawerConstraints()
}

func addDrawerConstraints() {
    drawerViewController.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    drawerViewController.view.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor, constant: 20).isActive = true
    drawerViewController.view.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
    drawerViewController.view.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
    drawerViewController.view.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: UIScreen.main.bounds.height).isActive = true
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    addDrawer()
}
```

Comment: “ I know I can reference single constraints with IBOutlets and name them but I want to learn how to build stuff programmatically without storyboard. ” Same way. When you create the constraint, name it. Or just keep a reference.

Comment: How can I name it? I think I just struggle with the syntax. I am really new to Swift

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I do this. It involves two things. First, set the constraints that will *always* be the same, setting `isActive = true`. Then, for the one (or more), activate/deactivate as needed:

```
let drawer = UIView()
var drawerOut = [NSLayoutConstraint]()
var drawerIn = [NSLayoutConstraint]()

// place in viewDidLoad()

drawer.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
drawer.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 526).isActive = true
drawer.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 374).isActive = true

drawerIn.append(drawer.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor, constant: 526))
drawerOut.append(drawer.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: safeAreaView.bottomAnchor, constant: -370))
NSLayoutConstraint.activate(drawerIn)

// functions to open/close drawer

func openDrawer() {
    NSLayoutConstraint.deactivate(drawerIn)
    NSLayoutConstraint.activate(drawerOut)
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3) { self.view.layoutIfNeeded() }
}

func closeDrawer() {
    NSLayoutConstraint.deactivate(drawerOut)
    NSLayoutConstraint.activate(drawerIn)
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3) { self.view.layoutIfNeeded() }
}
```

The `UIView.animate(withDuration:)` adds a nice animation to everything.

EDIT: Yes, you *can* name constraints and update them. For an example of this - changing a `heightAnchor` constant - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45144640/how-to-change-height-of-uiview-that-already-has-height-anchor/45146911#45146911). I took this question to be as much about how to *not* use IB for constraints as it is about *changing* a constraint.

Answer (score 0):

You say:

> As an IBO it would perfectly work like that:
>
> ```
> @IBOutlet private var containerViewTopConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!
> ```
>
> So I'd need to reference my topAnchor programmaticaclly and name it into containerViewTopConstraint.

Yes, so just do that. Where you have:

```
drawerViewController.view.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor, constant: 20).isActive = true
```

Put:

```
containerViewTopConstraint = drawerViewController.view.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor, constant: 20)
containerViewTopConstraint.isActive = true
```