# Constrain button to image inside UIImageView

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, uiimage

I have a `UIImageView` and the user can set the image so the `width/height` varies. I would like add a "x"- `button` to the upper right corner but NOT from the `UIImageView` but from the actual `image`.

Here is how it looks right now. The whole picture is the `UIImageView`, on the left you can see the `image` and on the right top corner you can see the `button`.

[image]

This is how I constrain it at the moment:

```
theStackView.addArrangedSubview(self.imageView)
imageContainerView.addSubview(wishImageView)
imageContainerView.addSubview(deleteImageButton)

imageContainerView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 60).isActive = true
imageContainerView.isHidden = true

wishImageView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: imageContainerView.leadingAnchor, constant: 20).isActive = true
wishImageView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: imageContainerView.topAnchor, constant: 3).isActive = true
wishImageView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: imageContainerView.bottomAnchor, constant: 3).isActive = true
wishImageView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: imageContainerView.trailingAnchor, constant: -20).isActive = true

deleteImageButton.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 10).isActive = true
deleteImageButton.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 10).isActive = true
deleteImageButton.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: wishImageView.topAnchor, constant: 5).isActive = true
deleteImageButton.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: wishImageView.trailingAnchor, constant: -5).isActive = true
```

This is obviously wrong but is there a way to constrain it to the actual `image`?

Comment: Is this UIImageView size is fixed?

Comment: @DilanAnuruddha yes it is

Comment: @DilanAnuruddha but the picture inside of it can change

Comment: what is your UIImageView contentMode?

Comment: @DilanAnuruddha left

Comment: @DilanAnuruddha well it is actually `aspectFit` and `left`, have a CustomClass for that

Comment: @Chris Hey buddy, your life would be so much simpler if your imageView wasn't any larger than you needed the actual image to be. Are you using a stack view? I'm curious what contains your imageView.

Comment: @Rob hey man :D yes I know.. But I honestly don't know how to do that, because the `width` changes with every picture..

Comment: @Chris Pop into the chat if you like.

Comment: If you are dynamically changing images, I think you'll need to do two things. (1) Create a two "named" constraints for `top` and `leading`... see my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45144640/how-to-change-height-of-uiview-that-already-has-height-anchor/45146911#45146911 (2) Use the `size` property of `UIImage` to calculate the **scaled** size of the current image to find where in the `UIImageView` to place the button, and adjust the constraints appropriately.

Comment: @dfd sorry I don't quite understand what you mean. Can you elaborate  on that? Also, I updated the question and added more code

Comment: 1/2... every view eventually has a frame, I typically use `viewDidLayoutSubviews` but you can do this earlier in the view lifecycle. So let's say `wishImageView` has a frame of `CGRect(10,10,1000,1000)` to keep the numbers fairly easy. Now, let's say your `UIImage` is sized at 4000w by 2000h. A `contentMode` means it's scaled down to 1000w by 500h in your image view, and it;'s origin is x == 0 and y == 1000-500 / 2 == 250. (Calculate this in your code.) In other words, the image would appear at CGRect(0,250,1000,500).

Comment: 2/2... ok. Apologies for taking time for my next comment. I'll post a complete answer that works. I thought that would be the best way to help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I put together a sample project that the repo is [here](https://github.com/justdfd/CloseButtonInImageView).

Basically you need to do a few things:

- Calculate *both* your `UIImageView` frame size along with the frame of the `UIMage` being displayed in `scaledAspectFit`.
- Create two named constraints and dynamically reposition your button once you have its frame.

For the first, you need to remember that the frames may not really be set until `viewDidLayoutSubviews`. I create a `UIImageView` extension that easily computes where the `UIImage` frame really is. (It's old but working code. I'm sure it can be improved.)

```
extension UIImageView {
    public var scaleFactor:CGFloat {
        guard let image = self.image, self.frame != CGRect.zero  else {
            return 0.0
        }

        let frame = self.frame
        let extent = image.size
        let heightFactor = frame.height/extent.height
        let widthFactor = frame.width/extent.width

        if extent.height > frame.height || extent.width > frame.width {
            if heightFactor < 1 && widthFactor < 1 {
                if heightFactor > widthFactor {
                    return widthFactor
                } else {
                    return heightFactor
                }
            } else if extent.height > frame.height {
                return heightFactor
            } else {
                return widthFactor
            }
        } else if extent.height < frame.height && extent.width < frame.width {
            if heightFactor < widthFactor {
                return heightFactor
            } else {
                return widthFactor
            }
        } else {
            return 1
        }
    }

    public var imageSize:CGSize {
        if self.image == nil {
            return CGSize.zero
        } else {
            return CGSize(width: (self.image?.size.width)!, height: (self.image?.size.height)!)
        }
    }

    public var scaledSize:CGSize {
        guard let image = self.image, self.frame != CGRect.zero  else {
            return CGSize.zero
        }
        let factor = self.scaleFactor
        return CGSize(width: image.size.width * factor, height: image.size.height * factor)
    }
}
```

For the second bullet you need to create two variables of type `NSConstraint`. I adapted [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45144640/how-to-change-height-of-uiview-that-already-has-height-anchor/45146911#45146911) from two years ago for this:

```
var btnTop:NSLayoutConstraint!
var btnTrailing:NSLayoutConstraint!
```

And in `viewDidLoad:

```
button.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 20).isActive = true
button.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 20).isActive = true

btnTop = button.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: imageView.topAnchor, constant: 10)
btnTop.isActive = true
btnTrailing = button.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: imageView.trailingAnchor, constant: -10)
btnTrailing.isActive = true
```

Note that you need to code two lines for each constraint! I never figured out why, but if you try to add the `isActive` property with the actual constraint the compiler doesn't know the correct type of the variable.

Now, you tie all this together in `viewDidLayoutSubviews`:

```
let scaledSize = imageView.scaledSize
var imageFrame = CGRect(origin: CGPoint.zero, size: scaledSize)
if scaledSize.width == imageView.frame.width {
    // image fills view along width, calculate Y constant
    imageFrame.origin.y = (imageView.frame.height - scaledSize.height) / 2
} else {
    // image fills view along height, calculate X constant
    imageFrame.origin.x = (imageView.frame.width - scaledSize.width) / 2
}
//btnTop.constant = imageFrame.width - 30
btnTop.constant = imageFrame.origin.y + 10
btnTrailing.constant = ((imageView.frame.width - imageFrame.width - imageFrame.origin.x) * -1) - 10
```

Placing the button in the top left is *much* simpler - it took me a good 20 minutes to get the correct calculation to make it top right instead!

In my test project I encapsulated this code in `repositionCloseButton()`, which would be called anytime the app displays a new image. This should work in both portrait and landscape orientation, and both portrait and landscape images - positioning a 20x20 close button 10 points away from the top right of an image.

Answer (score 1):

Use your image width to position the button. Get rough idea and smooth the UI

```
 let imgWidth = iv.image?.size.width

    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
        iv.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor),
        iv.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor),
        iv.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor),
        iv.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor),

        btn.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 20),
        btn.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 20),
        btn.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: iv.leadingAnchor , constant: (imgWidth ?? 0) > iv.frame.width ? iv.frame.width-20 : imgWidth ?? 0),
 //The issue happen when Image width is larger than the your imageview.Validate it for better result.
        btn.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: iv.topAnchor,constant: 10)

    ])
```

[image: Result]

Comment: thanks for the answer, probably right as well but I went with @dfd's idea