# How do I update constraints after changing UIButton's image

Tags: ios, swift, nslayoutconstraint

I have a mini game in my project where you have to guess a flag of a country, I don't use Interface Builder, all UI is written in code. When user taps one of the flags I load new set of countries to guess, set their flags to buttons and since flags are different in sizes from previous ones I need to adjust UIButton constraints so I call my function setupConstraints() which looks like that:

```
 func setupConstraints() {
    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
        countryNameLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor, constant: 10),
        countryNameLabel.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor),
        countryNameLabel.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.widthAnchor, constant: -20),
        countryNameLabel.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 30),
        
        firstCountryButton.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: countryNameLabel.bottomAnchor, constant: 35),
        firstCountryButton.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor),
        firstCountryButton.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 120),
        firstCountryButton.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: firstCountryButton.heightAnchor, multiplier: flagImages[0].getAspectRatio()),
        
        secondCountryButton.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: firstCountryButton.bottomAnchor, constant: 25),
        secondCountryButton.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor),
        secondCountryButton.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 120),
        secondCountryButton.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: secondCountryButton.heightAnchor, multiplier: flagImages[1].getAspectRatio()),
        
        thirdCountryButton.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: secondCountryButton.bottomAnchor, constant: 25),
        thirdCountryButton.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor),
        thirdCountryButton.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 120),
        thirdCountryButton.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: thirdCountryButton.heightAnchor, multiplier: flagImages[2].getAspectRatio()),
    ])
}
```

This function works fine when I initially setup my View Controller but when I call it to update constraints I get in log following:

```
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. 
    Try this: 
        (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; 
        (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. 
(
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x280d92940 UIButton:0x102315180.height == 120   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x280d92990 UIButton:0x102315180.width == 1.5*UIButton:0x102315180.height   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x280db2b70 UIButton:0x102315180.width == 2*UIButton:0x102315180.height   (active)>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x280db2b70 UIButton:0x102315180.width == 2*UIButton:0x102315180.height   (active)>
```

I see that it's trying to set width twice but I don't know why. I'm not even sure if my approach to call this function every time to setup constraints is the right one.

Comment: You'll need to keep a reference to your original constraint. To update it, then just set its `constant` property to something else.

Comment: Looks like this is one of my most upvoted answers: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45144640/how-to-change-height-of-uiview-that-already-has-height-anchor/45146911#45146911

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one way to handle it:

Create a struct ButtonSizeConstraints:

```
struct ButtonSizeConstraints {
   let widthConStraint: NSLayoutConstraint
   let heightConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint
}
```

Give your view an array of `ButtonSizeConstraints`, once for each button. (You could also have separate variables `firstButtonSizeConstraints`, `secondButtonSizeConstraints`, etc, but by making it an array you can loop through it.)

In your `setupConstraints` function, put those constraints into local vars, add them to your array of `ButtonSizeConstraints`, and activate them outside of the code you posted.

Then, when you load a new image into one or more of your buttons, fetch that button's `ButtonSizeConstraints`, update that constraint's constant value, and call the parent view's `layoutIfNeeded()` method.

Comment: Thank you! Works like a charm but I would love if you could review if I implemented it the right way. You can access my code here: [codeshare](https://codeshare.io/zy7d9r)

Comment: It looks reasonable, assuming your code to adjust the button constraints does what you want it to. (I don't know enough about your app to tell)

Comment: Yeah it does exactly what I want it to